# Adding a zoom function in D3 reusable charts using ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, es6-class

I am switching a reusable D3 v5 chart over to use ES6 classes and am having trouble implementing functions that update variables like a zoom function. So far I have a working map:

```
class myMap{
  constructor(args = {}){

    this.data = args.data;
    this.topo = args.topo;
    this.element =document.querySelector(args.element);
    this.width =args.width || this.element.offsetWidth;
    this.height = args.height || this.width / 2;


    this.setup();
 }

setup(){
this.projection = d3.geoMercator()
                         .translate([(this.width/2), (this.height/2)])
                         .scale( this.width / 2 / Math.PI);

this.path = d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection);

   // zoom fuction inserted here
  this.element.innerHTML ='';
    this.svg =d3.select(this.element).append("svg")
                 .attr("width", this.width)
                 .attr("height", this.height)
                 //.call(zoom)
                 .append("g");

  this.plot = this.svg.append("g");  
   d3.json(this.topo).then( world => {

    var topo = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

    this.draw(topo);
    });

   }


draw(topo){

var country = this.plot.selectAll(".country")
                 .data(topo);

  country.enter().insert("path")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("d", this.path)
      .attr('id', 'countries')
      .attr("fill", #cde)
      .attr("class", "feature");

  }
 //move(){} goes here  

}
```

which is called using:

```
const chart = new myMap({
  element: '#map',
    data: DATA_IN_JSON,
    topo:"../../../LINK_to_topojsonfile"});
```

When using functions I added zooming by using a variable and calling the move function, with a `.call(zoom)` appended to the SVG:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 9])
    .on("zoom", move);

function move() {
  g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.transform.k + "px");
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

Using the classes I tried declaring zoom in the `setup()` part of the class and calling move form `.on("zoom", this.move)` and attaching a `call` function to the SVG as marked in comments above. but I get a  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at SVGSVGElement.move` in the move function when referencing `this.plot`

```
const zoom = d3.zoom()
               .scaleExtent([1, 9])
               .on("zoom", this.move);

 move() {
   this.plot
       .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.transform.k + "px");
   this.plot
       .attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @altocumulus nope not really this is asking a specific case of using the .bind(this) to access an event handler inside a class not inside a function which is the case you listed as a duplicate.

Comment: You are right, my bad! I wanted to have this closed as duplicate of ["es6 Javascript class using this inside a callback \[duplicate\]"](/q/36498029) which is the same for class methods. That question is marked as duplicate of the one I mistakenly refered to first. Nonetheless, the same principles apply as JS classes are merely the often quoted syntactic sugar for the underlying prototypal language.

Comment: @altocumulus I agree the concepts are the same but I would never be able to find an answer to my case by just by searching SO.

Comment: That's why duplicate questions—as long as they are good quality—are neither deleted nor considered bad; they are just different entry points to the same problem. I had already started writing my own answer expanding on rioV8's post when I figured that this topic must have been covered multiple times before, which, as it turned out, it has been. Both questions linked to in my previous comments explain very well the three solutions that come mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bind `this`

```
const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 9])
    .on("zoom", this.move.bind(this));
```

console.log the `this` inside the `move()`

Comment: Ok that worked. So now I have to figure out what the bind(this) part does. Thanks not sure why you got down voted